# What is the system call(s) which retrieves the states of sockets in netstat?

Tags: linux, sockets

What is the system call(s) which retrieves the states of sockets in netstat? I am not actually interested in how netstat is implemented, but in what system call(s) can retrieve that information. `getsockopt()` seems to get the static information of sockets, not the dynamic/running states of sockets.

`ss` and `netstat` seem to take   different approaches, according to what [iproute document](https://www.cyberciti.biz/files/ss.html) says:

> This utility presents a new approach, which is supposed to scale well. I am not going to describe technical details here and will concentrate on description of the command. The only important thing to say is that it is not so bad idea to load module tcp_diag, which can be found in directory Modules of iproute2. If you do not make this ss will work, but it falls back to /proc and becomes slow like netstat, well, a bit faster yet (see section "Some numbers").

Does `ss` use some system calls to get the running states of sockets?

Comment: Its actually done via either the /proc filesystem or opening the network devices directly to get info from the driver.  So the system calls involved are just open and read and perhaps ioctl.

Comment: Thanks. Does `ss` use some system calls to get the running states of sockets?

Comment: [Looks like](https://github.com/sivasankariit/iproute2/blob/master/misc/ss.c#L120) ss uses /proc/net/* and standard C FILE* api.

Comment: @KamilCuk Then how differently does ss do from netstat?

Comment: Run them both under `strace` and compare.

Comment: Well, for starters, `ss` was developed by Alexey Kuznetosv, while `netstat` was written by Fred Baumgarten, Alan Cox, Tuan Hoang. What do you mean by that question? The source code is open, inspect the source code and compare.

Answer (score 2):

It's using the "netlink protocol" to accrue the data from the network stack, the transport layer engines within the kernel.

The netlink protocol is more generic than that, so not only covering socket stats for completeness sake.

For sockets specifically it's 
the [http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sock_diag.7.html][sockdiag] subsystem.

There are also more recent implementations of ss, e.g. [https://github.com/svinota/pyroute2/blob/master/cli/ss2][ss2] in python. From there, perusing it, getting a gist is simpler.

Cheers.